# how to write a testable code for the controller

Tags: php, laravel

I've written a laravel code and I'm frustrated because I think whatever I wrote is a bad code and can't be tested. I'll post my code.

As you can see I'm using models directly in controller. but I just need the best way to know how to write laravel controller code to be so flexible and testable. My code that I'm showing here seems so untestable in my opinion. what do you think?

This is my controller:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{

    protected $auth;
    protected $notification;

    public function __construct(AuthHelper $auth, NotificationHelper $notification){
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->notification = $notification;
    }


    public function loginUser(UserLoginRequest $request){
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        return $this->auth->generateJwtAndRefreshToken($credentials);
    }


    public function registerUser(UserRegisterRequest $request){
        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password =  \Hash::make($request->password);
        $user->country_id = $request->country_id;
        $user->phone = $request->phone;
        $user->address = $request->address;

        return $this->auth->registerUserHelper($request, $user, $this->notification);
    }
}
```

This is my helper class

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Helpers;

use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;
use App\Http\Models\Users\User;
use App\Http\Models\Users\TokenUser;
use App\Http\Helpers\NotificationHelper;
use App\Http\Models\Users\EmailConfirmation;
use App\Http\Models\Users\PasswordResetConfirmation;
use App\Http\Models\Permissions\Role;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use DB;

class AuthHelper {

    // generates guuid which will be called refresh token.
    public function generateRefreshToken(){
        mt_srand((double)microtime()*10000); //optional for php 4.2.0 and up.
        $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
        $hyphen = chr(45);// "-"
        $uuid = substr($charid, 0, 8).$hyphen
            .substr($charid, 8, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,12, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,16, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,20,12);
        return  $uuid;
    }



    /* generates access and refresh token while logging a user */
    public function generateJwtAndRefreshToken($credentials){
        try {
            if (! $access_token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['message' => trans("errors.user_not_exists")], 404);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(['message' => trans("errors.500")], 500);
        }
        $refresh_token = $this->generateRefreshToken();
        $user = JWTAuth::user();
        $refreshTokenUser = TokenUser::updateOrCreate(
            ['user_id' => $user->id],
            ['refresh_token' => $refresh_token, 'expiration_date' => Carbon::now()->addMinutes(\Config::get("jwt.refresh_token_expiration"))]
        );
        if(!$refreshTokenUser){
            return response()->json(['message' => trans("errors.500") ], 500);
        }
        return response()->json([ 
            'access_token' => $access_token,
            'refresh_token' => $refresh_token
        ], 200);
    }


    public function registerUserHelper($request, $user, $notification){
        $confirmation_code = str_random(6);
        DB::beginTransaction();
        try{
            $role_id = Role::where("name", $request->role_name)->first()->id;
            EmailConfirmation::create([
                'code' => $confirmation_code, 
                'email' => $request->email, 
                'expires_at' => Carbon::now()->addHour()
            ]);
            $user->save();
            $user->roles()->attach($role_id);
            $userTokens  = $this->generateJwtAndRefreshToken($request->only("email", "password"));
            if($userTokens->status() != 200) throw new \Exception();

            DB::commit();
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            DB::rollback();
            return response()->json(['message'=> trans('errors.500')],500); 
        }

        $notification->sendMail(['to' => $request->email, 'template_name' =>'RegisterVerification', 'confirmation' => $confirmation_code]);
        return response()->json(['message'=> trans('errors.registered'),'user_token' => $userTokens->getOriginalContent()], 200); 

    }
```

Comment: First off use [uuid package](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) to generate your uuids. Secondly you need to test the controller itself by hitting the routes that correspond to the methods, yes some call it integration testing some feature testing. Before each test you need to set up test data (factories), run the test (by hitting the controller via route), and tear down the database and repeat. By testing AuthHelper / NotificationHelper separately you will cover more code.

Comment: I just don't understand some parts. let's say I am testing registerUserHelper method in my helper class. there're models in it . Let's say I pass the data.($request, $user, $notification).   So what I do in my test is check if database contains records after executing this helper class function. I'm curious how my code could be written to be more testable. with that, I'd understand more.

Comment: I am not sure if its OK to move the question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but maybe it is. You need to read on the concepts of testing first a bit, maybe watch a video or two; the key is to do some action in isolated environment and verify that it went OK + data is correct. So you need to be able to set up the isolated environment (like have a record in a database) do some test on it (change it) and then compare the results, was the record changed? is it changed to the correct value? if yes then destroy everything and move to next test.

Answer (score 0):

For this I suggest you to use two patterns.

1. Repository pattern, which helps you create a layer between your model and model client. So, everything will be accessed from repository rather model and model will be used to write each repository. https://medium.com/employbl/use-the-repository-design-pattern-in-a-laravel-application-13f0b46a3dce this link can clarify you more on repository pattern.
2. Service Layer, this would be a layer which contain all your business logic classes as a Service. Eventually, you will use services in your controller. https://m.dotdev.co/design-pattern-service-layer-with-laravel-5-740ff0a7b65f this may clarify service layer.

Basically, services use repository to make all database interaction rather doing them directly in the controller.